# Local class incompatible error when only a method has changed

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility, serializable

I just came across *"WTF"* sort of error: I updated one of my classe's methods and added one method too. After running my program, this is what popped our when program tried to open and unserialize recently saved data (before the methods changes):

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: cz.autoclient.settings.Settings; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2404650814140543454, local class serialVersionUID = 4256355437298300223
```

According to what java documentation says about that, java methods are not being serialized. So why does the `serialVersionUID` take class methods in account too?

Since Java programmers seem to be so mad about using getters and setters literally everywhere, why is it not possible to create getter for `serialVersionUID` so that I can implement my own algorithm that only calculates the properties?

The [`serialVersionUID` can be overriden](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), but only with `static final long serialVersionUID` value which would require me to remember to change it when I change class's properties.

Comment: Based on what it says in the specs, this should not happen. Tomas, can you share the class definition of the class you serialized with and without the modifications?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what all have I changed, but I can assure you this is not the first time it happened. A actually posted it because this thing was getting me real angry. I will try to invent a test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation for java, they recommend to use custom `serialVersionUID` as much as possible, because the default algorithm will take class implementation details and the result is said to vary from JVM implementation to another.

The [default algorithm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) used by Java to generate the `serialVersionUID` seems to be considering the non-private methods (step 7) as well. Which explains the exception if you were using the default `serialVersionUID` in your implementation.

EDIT:
As you suggested, it would be great if we can have our own implementation of a method to do this, rather than overriding the `serialVersionUID` as a `static final long`. But I guess they don't allow that because if it were allowed, wrong implementations of such a method could invalidate the whole purpose of the `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: Why would I want any way to distinguish the two versions? Class is just a data holder with some functions that operate on it. As long as the data are the same, nobody cares what functions you used.

Comment: I would swear I already posted that comment above. What the hell is going on with this website? Good I have Lazarus addon to remember anything I post for these situations.

Comment: In reply to your edit: forgeting to update `serialVersionUID` manually causes your program to crash instead of handling the exception.

Comment: Yes I agree with you in this situation. What I mean to say is that the default implementation of `serialVersionUID` cannot be trusted. So its always safe to override it, so you can determine whether the change you made to the class require a `serialVersionUID` update or not.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) indicate that if you do not provide a `serialVersionUID`, the compiler will generate one for you.

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification. **However, it is strongly recommended that all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during deserialization**. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not useful as inherited members. Array classes cannot declare an explicit serialVersionUID, so they always have the default computed value, but the requirement for matching serialVersionUID values is waived for array classes.

And according to the [Java Object Serialization Specification section 5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html)

> Versioning raises some fundamental questions about the identity of a class, including what constitutes a compatible change. A **compatible change** is a change that does not affect the contract between the class and its callers.

What's happening here is that the compiler has decided the difference between the two versions of your code warrant a new `serialVersionUID`. If you feel that the state contained in an instance of Object(1) and Object(2) are interchangeable, you should manage this by setting the `serialVersionUID` manually and keeping it the same between those changes.

Yes, you will have to manually manage this, and change it when you make changes to the mechanisms which manage the internal state of the class.

As a note though, if the public methods have changed, you should consider if the original version of the class meets the same expectations as the new version. If you would like the data contained in the previously-serialized state to be loaded into a new version of the class, perhaps use a static constructor method to initialize the new version (new behavior) with the compatible, old state.

Comment: This definitelly seems like something that is not correctly implemented on Java side then. `class and its callers` have nothing to do with serialization, that's something compiler should check. If you unserialize class without method to class with method, there will be no problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree -- if I have a `class Dog` that has internal `String name` and one `method bark()` and then I change the class to have a new `method barkMyName()`, and you unserialize an old `dog` with the new class, it will not be able to bark its name. Thus, the caller should not expect to be able to send that message to this instance.

Comment: And if you would like to be able to unserialize a class without the method (old) to one with the method (new), that is something you must manage by maintaining the same `serialVersionUID` between the two.

Comment: To add from Bloch's *Effective Java*, "If you do not specify this number explicitly by declaring a `static final long` field named `serialVersionUID`, the system automatically generates it at runtime by applying a complex procedure to the class. The automatically generated value is affected by the class's name, the names of the interfaces it inherits, and all of its **public and protected members**." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Andy I'm not sure if you're imagining the situation correctly. If you have the old implementation of class with `bark()` and you unserialize the `Dog` you do not really expect for any reason that the Dog could `barkMyName` because this method is not in your sourcecode. Further more, you could instead have `pissMyNameInSnow` method and use the serialized `name` to execute it. I feel like OOP is really confusing people.

Comment: My point is that the expectations for object behavior are defined by the current version of the class at the time of unserialization, not serialization. Perhaps I used poor example methods, but this is the objective of `serialVersionUID` -- to avoid unserializing object state into an instance of the object that performs different behavior. If you feel the internal state is the only thing that matters and all behavior is backward-compatible, manually manage the `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: You need to start understanding that methods are not data. When you unserialize the class, you don't even have to have any methods actually. you're unserializing **data**, not part of the program. Or did you see a Java application that stores `serialVersionUID` in database and converts whole database to new version after every update? I don't think so.

Comment: Java serialization is often used with remote systems -- there is a compiled version of the class on machine A and on machine B and the serialized state is sent between them. I've explained the available mechanism for communicating to the system that you feel two different versions of the class are compatible if the methods are different. You're welcome to disagree with how Java implements this.